# The $\sigma$-algebra of measurable sets is invariant under multiplication

Tags: measure-theory

The question is: for every measurable set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ and every $t \in \mathbb{R}$, show that $tA$ is measurable, where $tA=\lbrace tx | x \in A \rbrace$.

Now, I have already shown that for the outer measure $m^{*}$, $m^{*}(tA)=|t|m^{*}(A)$. To show that $tA$ is measurable, I want to verify that the Caratheodory condition holds: $E$ is measurable if for every $A \subset \mathbb{R}$, $m^{*}(A)=m^{*}(A \cap E) + m^{*}(A \cap E^{c})$.

Since $m^{*}(A)\le m^{*}(A \cap E) + m^{*}(A \cap E^{c})$ always hold, we need to only check that $m^{*}(A)\ge m^{*}(A \cap E) + m^{*}(A \cap E^{c})$.

For this particular question, I am stuck on the first step. I took an arbitrary $B \subset \mathbb{R}$, and now I need to show that $m^{*}(B)\ge m^{*}(B \cap tA)+ m^{*}(B\cap tA^{c})$.

I want to use $B \cap A \subset B \cap tA$, but I don't think that it is correct.

Any advice, hints, suggestions would be greatly appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $t \neq 0$. Note that $tx \in B \cap tA $ iff $x \in A$ and $x \in t^{-1}B$, i.e.  $ \ x \in t^{-1}B \cap A$. This shows that

$$B \cap tA = t(t^{-1}B \cap A).$$

Using this fact, what you've already shown, and the measurability of $A$ we have

$$ m^*(B \cap tA) + m^*(B \cap tA^c) = |t|m^*(t^{-1}B \cap A) + |t|m^*(t^{-1}B \cap A^c) = |t|m^*(t^{-1}B) = m^*(B).$$

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you!